# Mysql collapse/merge rows

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
ID   Name      Field2      Field3
1    Steve     Value1      <null>
1    Steve     <null>      Value2
```

How do I merge these rows into one row that looks like this:

```
1    Steve     Value1      Value2
```

The row count for ID/Name might vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, name, max(field2), max(field3)
from your_table
group by id, name
```